# MySQL + VB.NET - Select all MySQL Rows in a table one by one in a loop

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm writing a program for Employees Management and i need to automatically generate a Payroll for each one then calculate some things and save it to another table.

I know how to calculate and save. I just need to get all the ID column of all rows in my Employees table, and select each Employee ID one by one in order to calculate each payroll automatically.

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the information you need to look up based on the employeeID is in one other table, you may wish to use an Inner Join to select all the SQL data you need at once.  Something like this:

```
SELECT tblEmployee.EmployeeID, PayRate FROM tblEmployee INNER JOIN tblPayRates ON tblEmployee.EmployeeID= tblPayRates.EmployeeID
```

In the select make sure you add the table name for any fields that are the same in both tables. Then you could make a list of items that hold all the data you collected, or calculate and store that information in whatever format you need it.

If you really only want the Ids from a single table that would look like this:

```
SELECT EmployeeID FROM tblEmployee
```

The code for generating the query and getting results will look something like this:

```
    Dim cn As New MySqlConnection(ConnectionString)
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(Query, cn)
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
    Dim IdList as new List(Of Integer)

    Do While reader.Read
        IdList.add(reader.GetInt32(0))
    Loop

    reader.Close()
    cmd.Dispose()
    cn.Close()
```

I used a list of Integer to hold the result since I am not sure what type your ID is.

If you have more than one field in the select you would add it to the loop, changing the type you are getting if necessary and then incrementing the index (reader.GetString(1) for example)

I am not sure which part of all this you weren't sure how to proceed with... so I hope this went the right direction.

Comment: Tried with For Each and with While, both worked like a charm! Will stay with the method. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

I would make an object for it called myEmployee or something.
Then get your entire table and put it in a list.
Make sure that the object has all properties needed, so in this case that would be all your colls you need for the calculation.
You will get

```
Dim myList as List(Of myEmployee) = *function that returns you the table*
```

Once you done that you can loop through that.

```
For Each result as myEmployee in myList
"Execute functions for calculating and saving it to the other table"
Next
```

That way you have all your results in a list, and you can easily loop through all of those one by one.
The execution of this code is probably not good enough but as long as you can see the basic idea of this the way I had it in mind you will see where I am going :)

Hope this can be of any help